# Changing jquery UI dialogue titlebar HTML from span to H2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using a JQuery UI dialogue and it renders the below HTML. I want the span tag to be replaced with H2 tag, do we have any way to do this

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header">
    <span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-id-20">
    </span>
```

I am using the Jquery UI 1.11

Comment: Any reason you can't just style that the same as your H2?  Styling for title is here: https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-title.  Why does it need to actually be an `<h2>` element?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the following example, based on https://api.jqueryui.com/1.11/dialog/#entry-examples

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    create: function(e, ui) {
      var w = $(this).dialog("widget");
      var t = $(".ui-dialog-title", w);
      var h2 = $("<h2>", {
        id: t.attr("id"),
        class: t.attr("class")
      }).html(t.text());
      t.replaceWith(h2);
    }
  });
  $("#opener").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog</div>
```

Please see:

https://api.jqueryui.com/1.11/dialog/#event-create

You can inject your own code or elements during the `create` callback.